# Modify a text file - Android

Tags: android, regex, file

I am trying to read a text file from /sdcard/test.txt from within my app.  I'm successfully reading it into a buffer and regexing it.  The regex works in an online tester, so I don't think that's the problem.  I don't think my repalceAll() method is sticking.  When I open the file, nothing has been changed.  I know how to create/overwrite a text file, but how do I change specific strings within it like this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + fileName;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        /*Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/


        try
        {
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sCurrentLine, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                regex(sCurrentLine);
            }
            buffer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static void regex(String chord) {
        //String notes = "^[CDEFGAB]";
        String notes = "^[C]";
        String accidentals = "[#|##|b|bb]";
        //String chords = "[maj7|maj|min7|min|sus2]";
        String regex = notes + accidentals;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(chord);
        //System.out.println("regex is " + regex);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            regex.replaceAll(regex, "D");
            int i = matcher.start();
            int j = matcher.end();
            //System.out.println("i:" + i + " j:" + j);
        }
        else {
            //System.out.println("no match!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `String.replaceAll()` will not modify the argument, but will instead return a new string.  However, you aren't using the return value in any way in your code, so that may be your problem.  String is immutable, and methods that make modifications to it will always return a brand new String.